# Find solution set with 2 equations and 4 variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I just had exam 1 for Intro to Linear Algebra. There was a question to find solution set of the system with 2 equations and 4 variables. Something like:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1 +& x_2& &+ x_4 &= 5\\
&&x_3 &+ x_4 &= 8
\end{cases}
$$
(I am sure that in the first equation there were $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_4$, in the second $x_3$ and $x_4$, but I am not sure about coefficients)

Now if there were 2 equations and 3 variables I would replace third (free) variable with $t$ ($x_3 = t$), where $t$ is any real number, thus it gives us solution set. However, I am not sure what was I supposed to do with 2 free variables ($x_3$ and $x_4$)? My answer was that system is inconsistent and there were no solutions.

Is there some kind of question bank with Linear Algebra common exam equations? I need to prepare myself better for exams 2 and 3.

Comment: Subtract the second equation from the first:  $x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = -3$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{cases}x_1=5-x_2-x_4,\\x_3=8-x_4\end{cases}$$ where $x_2,x_4$ are free parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the second equation from the first to find:

$$x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = −3$$

[image]